# Push buttons switch

Tags: button

Maybe someone can help me out here. I have tried looking all over for a push button switch that is 4 pronged and can turn on 2 separate devices at the same time. I need to be able to turn on a air pump and atomizer together. All the push buttons I have found only allow for 1 device. I am looking for push buttons that are from 10 - 20 mm. Thank you for any help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: The magic word is "DPST". Failing that, try "DPDT".

Comment: what do you want to happen when you release the switch?

Comment: Once the switch is released it will cut both systems off. I talked to my supplier and they are able to make the correct momentary push buttons for me  DPDT thank yall again

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll need a DPST or DPDT momentary OFF-(ON) switch. Use filters on Mouser or Digi-key to search.

Comment: Thanks! I do believe that is what I am looking for! Yall are awesome!

Comment: @TimothyBradly glad we could help. Could you please click accept this answer so I can get my street cred points? ;)